# How to Display Progress bar from Windows shell in TKinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, progress-bar

I am running an "Any file type to PDF Convertor" code using python. When I convert Word files to PDF, it displays a progress bar in the Windows Shell like so:

[image: Progress Bar In Shell]

But I want this progress bar to be displayed inside the Tkinter window.
Is there a way to do this?
Because when I run it as an exe, I cannot let "-w" stay there otherwise the program crashes.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from tkinter import filedialog
def buttonclick():
    root.filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="Pictures", title="Select File", filetypes=(("All Files","*.*"),("PNG Files","*.png"),("JPG Files","*.jpg")))
    try:
        locus=root.filename.split(".")
        dest=str(locus[0]+".pdf")
        if str(locus[-1])=="docx":
            from docx2pdf import convert
            '''
            import ttk as t
            progressbar = t.Progressbar(orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate')
            progressbar.pack(side="bottom")
            '''
            convert(root.filename,dest)
            #progressbar.start()
            notifier=Label(root, text="File converted to PDF successfully!", fg="green", bg="#BFDFFF").pack()
        elif str(locus[-1])=="pdf":
            notifier=Label(root, text="PDF file Selected! Choose another file type.", fg="black", bg="#BFDFFF").pack()
        elif str(locus[-1])=="":
            notifier=Label(root, text="Please select a file!", fg="black", bg="#BFDFFF").pack()
        else:
            imge=Image.open(root.filename)
            im1 = imge.convert('RGB')
            im1.save(dest)
            notifier=Label(root, text="File converted to PDF successfully!", fg="green", bg="#BFDFFF").pack()
    except:
        notifier=Label(root, text="An unexpected error occured!", fg="red", bg="#BFDFFF").pack()
root=Tk()
root.title("Any File to PDF Convertor")
root.config(bg="#BFDFFF")
root.geometry("300x200")
root.iconbitmap("D:\Coding\MyIcon.ico")
convert=Button(root, text="Select File",font=("Helvetica", 20), bg="#85FF97",command=lambda: buttonclick())
convert.pack(pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Basically you cannot move the console progress bar (produced by `tqdm` module inside `convert()` function) into tkinter application.  You can try rewriting `convert()` function using [`tqdm.tk`](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tk/) module.

Comment: okay thank you, I will try that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not try a progress bar widget. Check out this code. I did not bother adapting my solution to your case since you have accepted the answer:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import os



root = Tk()

# I set the length and maximum as shown to demonstrate the process in the 
# proceeding function. Pay attention to the increment r
progress = Progressbar(root, orient = HORIZONTAL,
            length = 200/5, maximum=200/5, mode = 'determinate')

# Function 


def my_func():
    t=0
    r= 1/5   
    for i in range(200):
        print(i) #whatever function interests you
        t=t+r
        progress['value'] = t
        root.update_idletasks()
  

progress.pack()

# Button
Button(root, text = 'Start', command = bar).pack(pady = 10)


mainloop()
```